# I can't get my if statement to execute properly

Tags: c

I can't seem to get my if statements to execute properly in the deposits & withdrawals portion of the program. It will execute properly when the number is negative but when it is positive it displays error message and then end the loop and moves to withdrawals.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int deposits = 0, totaldeposits = 0, deposited = 0, totalwithdrawals = 0, withdrawals, d = 0, w = 0;
    float balance = 0, b;

        printf ("Welcome to the computer banking system\n\n");

    for ( b = 0; b <= balance; ++b )
    {
        printf ("Enter your current balance in dollars and cents:");
            scanf ("%f", &b);
            balance = balance + b;

        if ( balance <= -1 )
        {
            printf ("***Beginning balance must be at least zero, please re-enter.\n\n");
                balance = balance - b, --b;

        }/*end of if statement*/
    }/*end of for loop*/

    for ( d = 0; d <= deposits; ++d )
    {       
        printf ("\nEnter the number of deposits (0-5):");
            scanf ("%i", &d);
        deposits = deposits + d;

        if ( deposits > 5 || deposits < 0 )
        {
            printf ("*** Invalid number of deposits, please re-enter.");
                deposits = deposits - d;
        }/*end of if statement for deposits*/       
    }/*end of for loop for deposits*/
    for ( w <= 0; w <= withdrawals; ++w)
    {
        printf ("\n\nEnter the number of withdrawals (0-5):");
            scanf ("%i", &w);
            withdrawals = withdrawals + w, ++w;

        if ( withdrawals > 5 || withdrawals < 0 )
        {
        printf ("***Invalid number of withdrawals, please re-enter.");
        withdrawals = withdrawals - w, --w;
        }/*end of withdrawals if*/
    }/*end of withdrawals for loop*/





getchar;        
return 0;

} /*End main*/
```

Comment: And *which* `if` statement would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have some error in the logic of your program. I would rewrite

```
for ( d = 0; d <= deposits; ++d )
{       
    printf ("\nEnter the number of deposits (0-5):");
        scanf ("%i", &d);
    deposits = deposits + d;

    if ( deposits > 5 || deposits < 0 )
    {
        printf ("*** Invalid number of deposits, please re-enter.");
            deposits = deposits - d;
    }/*end of if statement for deposits*/       
}/*end of for loop for deposits*/
```

as

```
do {
    printf ("\nEnter the number of deposits (0-5):");
    scanf ("%i", &deposits);

    if (deposits < 0 || deposits > 5) {
        printf ("*** Invalid number of deposits, please re-enter.");
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while (1);
```

The same could be done for other loops.

The idea is to ask for input at least one time and check if the entered value is valid for your case, if it's not, ask for input again.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help! I really appreciate it. I wasn't understanding the do loops but they are much more clear after this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable d in the for loop and for taking input.That is causing the problem.Use the following code:-

```
int dep;
for ( d = 0; d <= deposits; ++d )
{       
    printf ("\nEnter the number of deposits (0-5):");
        scanf ("%i", &dep);
    deposits = deposits + dep;

    if ( deposits > 5 || deposits < 0 )
    {
        printf ("*** Invalid number of deposits, please re-enter.");
            deposits = deposits - dep;
    }/*end of if statement for deposits*/  
    else break;     
}/*end o
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!